# using require.config in a vows file

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, requirejs, vows

I'm trying to setup require like it's set in the index.html document so that there aren't any problems... for some reason vowsjs is complaining about require.config...

maybe it's using an old requirejs version? 
vows 0.7.0

```
(ProjectEnv)obitusis@8675309 ~../static/js: sudo vows test_models.js

../static/js/test_models.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { require.config({
                                                                      ^
TypeError: Object function require(path) {
    return self.require(path);
  } has no method 'config'
    at Object.<anonymous> (../static/j
s/test_models.js:1:71)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at ProjectEnv/lib/node_modules/vows/bin/vow
s:567:19
    at Array.reduce (native)
    at importSuites (ProjectEnv/lib/node_module
s/vows/bin/vows:560:18)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I've fixed it... looks like i needed...

```
var require = require('requirejs')
```

UPDATE

```
var requirejs = require('requirejs') // guess their require ain't compatible
```

Check out:  [**Building node modules with AMD or RequireJS**](http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html#3) for more information.